# finding the volume of the pyramid (Calculus)

Tags: calculus

I am having a problem understanding this question:

- (a) find the volume of the pyramid shown in this figure by using a
  cross section  perpendicular to the edge of length c.
- (b) Find the volume of the pyramid shown in this figure by using
  cross sections perpendicular to the edge of length b.

I would appreciate any tip or hint on this. Perhaps if I can picture how to construct the cross sections then I can find the volume by integration. This picture confuses me a bit as I can't even say where the tip of the pyramid is!

[image]

Comment: If the vertex where the right angle is marked were the origin, the other vertices would be $ \ (a, 0, 0 ) \ , \ (0 , b , 0) \ \ \text{and} \ \ ( 0, 0, c) \ $ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part (a) each cross section will be a right triangle with one leg parallel to $b$ and the other parallel to $a$.  Your aim is to find a formula for this cross section in terms of the the height $x$ (from the origin) of the cross section.

Select a point of height $x$ along $c$.

[image]

By similar triangles the horizontal segment $y$ satisfies $$\frac{y}{c-x}=\frac{b}{c}$$ when, $$y=\frac{b(c-x)}{c}$$.  This is the length of one leg of your cross section in terms of $x$.  Repeat on the triangle with legs of length $c$ and $a$.  Once you have the lengths of the legs in terms of $x$, multiply and divide by two to get a formula for $A(x)$, the area of the cross section in terms of $x$.  You then want to evaluate $$\int_0^c A(x)\,dx$$.